# best practice for naming css color variables

Tags: css, naming-conventions, naming

It's a basic question but I want to know when defining main colors for an application, should the color classes be named by their color:

`pumpkin-orange`, `topaz`, `sky-blue`,`gray-color`

Or by their meaning/function :

`main-color`, `main-color-hover`,`secondary-color`,`link-color`,`disabled-color`...

Comment: meaning/function is the best way to go for support and changes on a site. What if you are using the variable topaz as an accent color and your client ask you to change that color. You will have to replace all the instances of the variable.

Comment: yes, but a second case, what if i need to match link color for the background of a button or the border of an image, should i put "link-color" as color of a background button or a border ?

Comment: yes, describe what the purpose is. Your focus should be DRY. Dont Repeat Yourself

Answer (score 11):

The best way to handle colors, especially in large, complex projects, is to use both, **branding** names and **functional** names, and combine them so that maintaining the project color palette becomes super easy.

1. Name all the colors you get from the design with their "color" names (`red-bright`, `red-light`, `red-pale`). This is independent from your project HTML, it is related only to the color palette that the designer chose as the current theme
2. Name each place in your project where any color is used with its functional name (`link-color`, `banner-color`, `banner-border`, `banner-bg`, `footer-bg`).

   These names are independent from the visual design.

   Only ever use functional names within the CSS code that is applied to HTML     elements. The only exception is if you're using CSS custom properties (`--var(name)`) color names are stated once on the `:root` so functional names can use them.
3. Connect the functional names to the appropriate color name as per the visual design. Keep the color palette themes and the connection between functional and branding colors in the same file (for example `_colors.scss`).

Example (here I'm simplifying the syntax just to illustrate the color-naming point, in reality you need to use CSS custom properties, Sass or LESS variables syntax):

```css
/* ===== Color theme—Bright ===== */  
blue:       #0000ff;  
green:      #008000;  
dark-green: #006400;  
neon-green: #00ff00;  
neon-blue:  #00ffff;  


/* ===== Project color definitions ===== */
/* All places where color is specified in the project */
/* Currently using the Bright design palette */  
link-color:          blue;  
banner-color:        green;  
banner-border:       dark-green;  
banner-bg:           neon-green;  
alert-status:        green;  
alert-status-border: dark-green;  
button-bg:           neon-blue;  
button-border:       blue;  
footer-bg:           neon-blue;
```

This way if you have to change anything color-related you only need to deal with this file, no need to sift through all of your CSS.

This process requires that each time you're adding new HTML to your project, with its CSS, you need to come up with the functional names for the new component, and only use functional names in your regular CSS. At the same time copy the newly added functional name to your colors file (`_colors.scss`) and define it with a branding color palette there.

### After a design revamp

If a new visual design comes along you can easily switch all the functional names with the new color names and change the colors for the entire project in 5 minutes!

```css
/* ===== Color theme—Bright ===== */  
blue:       #0000ff;  
green:      #008000;  
dark-green: #006400;  
neon-green: #00ff00;  
neon-blue:  #00ffff;  

/* ===== Color theme—Pale ===== */  
pale-blue:       #bbbbff;  
pale-green:      #a1c8a1;  
pale-dark-green: #506450;  
pale-neon-green: #ddffdd;  
pale-neon-blue:  #ccffff;  


/* ===== Project color definitions ===== */
/* All places where color is specified in the project */
/* Currently using the Pale design palette */  
link-color:          pale-blue;  
banner-color:        pale-green;  
banner-border:       pale-dark-green;  
banner-bg:           pale-neon-green;  
alert-status:        pale-green;  
alert-status-border: pale-dark-green;  
button-bg:           pale-neon-blue;  
button-border:       pale-blue;  
footer-bg:           pale-neon-blue;
```

You should delete the unused color palettes from your *compiled* CSS for better performance. This means that if you're using CSS custom properties you should delete the old branding color variables from the `:root` and add the new ones.

But you can keep the different branding color palette definitions
in the `_colors.scss` for future reference, because only the color palette that is used in the functional names will end up in the actual CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Select the names by meaning.
Colors could change, bud the meaning stays.

It would be nice if the community could agree on common names.
That way, you could use third-party code and their design would already be harmonised.

Here is an attempt:
https://github.com/nuxodin/css-variables-name-conventions

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid naming css classes by color. Use a functional name instead. I will advise you to have a look to [BEM naming convention](http://getbem.com/naming) . I think it is a good start to have a structured approach of css.